# Computer restarts on power failure with UPS

Tags: power-supply, reboot, ups

I am having power cut problems in my country. 
I am using an uninterrupted power supply with these specs

- waveform: modified sine wave
- typical 15-20ms, 30ms max

My computer restarts when power goes down, the UPS does take over but while it does the computer restarts.

Earlier my router used to restart as well but I fixed it (I noticed the adapter of router had input 220-240 V , changed the adapter to 110-220V  and now it does not restart)

My computer still restart Is there a solution for this ?
thanks,

Comment: Have you contacted the UPS manufacturers technical support?

Comment: *What* UPS are you using, and *how old* is it?  What voltage are your power outlets?

Comment: It sounds like your UPS is capable of supplying enough power to your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some power supplies don't like the large [THD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_harmonic_distortion) in pseudo-sine signals, although these are usually more expensive supplies (like the one mentioned in [this article](http://blog.samkendall.net/2010/03/22/hp-proliant-g6-series-server-issues-with-line-interactive-upss/)). These power supplies use an [active power factor correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_PFC#Active_PFC) technology, and this part has problems coping with irregular voltage signals.

But you should contact both the UPS and power supply manufacturers and give them the details. Since the PC *restarts* (and then continues running on battery), it means that it is connected to the correct socket and that UPS presumably has enough power, so it boils down to large switchover time or THD.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you PSU isn't really good. Getting a good brand one (like seasonic), that should solve the problem.

It would be good if you specified the load of the computer and your current PSU.